# Rails javascript asset cache not cleared by Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, http-caching

We're using Rails asset pipeline for javascripts. The application-xyz.js (xyz = digest) is cached and does not seem to get cleared by IE (version 8), even if i recompile all assets and redeploy to production. Even deleting history and temporary internet files does not help.

Is there any directive/header to make IE clear cached versions and always fetch latest version of the page?

Answer (score 1):

I use a meta tag in the header page.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" />
```

Info for this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

I hope it helps.